# PHP Undefined index when attempting to access key in array that exists

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a number of rows (ingredients) in a table in my database, I'm using the following code to iterate and populate my view with the name of each, but I want to be able to display the children/parents (columns in the DB) of each item, I'm able to log out the values correctly but when I try to echo as below I'm receiving "Message: Undefined index: parents" & "Message: Undefined index: children";

```
<?php foreach ($ingredient as $row => $key) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row + 1; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $key['name']; ?> </td>
        <?php ChromePhp::log($key['parents']); ?>
        <td><?php echo $key['parents']; ?> </td>
        <?php ChromePhp::log($key['children']); ?>
        <td><?php echo $key['children']; ?> </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm confused as I have no issue logging it out.
I assumed it may be due to null values so I assigned child/parent a string value for each row as follows;

[image]

but the error persists.

Here is the logged output in the browser;

[image]

Output of `<?php ChromePhp::log($key); ?>`

[image]

EDIT: Here is how I'm building the $ingredients array;

```
<?php

    function get_ingredient()
    {
        $qry = "SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(i.name, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(`name`, 2))) as name,i.id as id,'ingredient' as type, i.parents as parents, i.children as children FROM `ingredient` i WHERE i.is_del=0 order by i.name asc";
        $qry = $this->db->query($qry);

        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0) {
            $ingr = $qry->result_array();
        } else {
            $ingr = array();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I assume I'm missing something fundamental, any advise would be most appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: It's really hard to say, without knowing how `$ingredients` is being built.

Comment: As per my edit, you can see that the $ingredient array is populating correctly, I don't think adding something that is functioning as expect will enhance the question.

Comment: Are you getting an array of objects? Try `$key->parents`

Comment: @adam thanks, I tried that, it returns "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: `print_r($ingredients)` what is it?

Comment: OK that has exposed the problem, it seems that the $ingredient array contains both ingredients and recipes, where recipes do not have the parent and children columns. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My array had two sets of data, I have resolved this by limiting the array to one set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($ingredient as $row => $key) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row + 1; ?> </td>

    <?php if(isset($key['name']) && !empty($key['name'])):?>
    <td><?php echo $key['name']; ?> </td>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if(isset($key['parents']) && !empty($key['parents'])):?>
        <?php ChromePhp::log($key['parents']); ?>
        <td><?php echo $key['parents']; ?> </td>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if(isset($key['children']) && !empty($key['children'])):?>
        <?php ChromePhp::log($key['children']); ?>
        <td><?php echo $key['children']; ?> </td>
    <?php endif;?>
</tr>
```

Comment: ):)?> should be )):?>

Answer (score -1):

$key looks like an object so you have to access it with -> so to get value of name use $key->name,$key->parents